# Calculating percent results in 0

Tags: swift

I'm trying to calculate the percentage based on two values, but I seem to be getting a result of 0

The code is

```swift
    func calcPercent(value: Int, total: Int) -> Double {
        let val = value / total
        let perc = Double(val * 100)
        
        NSLog("Value: \(value)")
        NSLog("Total: \(total)")
        NSLog("Val: \(val)")
        NSLog("Perc: \(perc)")
        
        return perc
    }
```

The result I'm getting back is

Value: 46

Total: 151

Val: 0

Perc: 0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the issue is with the line where you calculate the val variable. You are performing integer division, which will result in an integer value rounded down to the nearest whole number. In this case, 46 divided by 151 will result in a value less than 1, which will be rounded down to 0.

To fix this, you can change the calculation of val to use floating-point division instead:

```
let val = Double(value) / Double(total)
```

This will ensure that the result is a floating-point number, which can then be used to calculate the percentage correctly.